# Choose specific localization on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, localization, locale

How can I let the user choose a specific localization in my app? I have a book and I'd like the users to be able to read all the different translations of it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement your own localisation methods.

One way to do this is to subclass NSBundle and override `-pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:` and `-pathsForResourcesOfType:inDirectory:forLocalization:`. In your overrides, read from NSUserDefaults or whatever to decide which localisation to use then manually find the right one.

Comment: What about strings? NSLocalizedString()

Comment: NSLocalizedString is simply a macro that expands to -[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:] (Command+Double-click NSLocalizedString in Xcode to see the definition). I imagine this routes through -pathForResource:(etc) to find the strings file. If not, you'd have to override -[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:...]  as well.

Comment: Thanks for all that. But it sounds like too much hassle.. I'll try to find another way to do this and I'll let you know.

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting your answer as correct, but I haven't had the time to try it our yet.